# PRISM - How to get DLL's name and version information?

Tags: silverlight-4.0, prism

Is it possible to get DLL's names and version information from a appmanifest.xml which resides in a VS2010 project corresponding to a PRISM Module ?

My Silverlight 4 application loads on demand all modules listed in the modules catalog. I guess this means that it has downloaded all the modules corresponding XAP files, appmanifest.xml files – to load the necessary resources (DLL’s, etc)

So, at this point, how can I access DLL's names and if possible DLL's version number of every module **from within my "main" Silverlight project** ??

Thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in the ModuleInit.cs of each PRISM module. Somewhat like:

```
public class ModuleInit : IModule
{
    private readonly IUnityContainer _container;
    private readonly IRegionManager _regionManager;

    public ModuleInit(IUnityContainer container, IRegionManager regionManager)
    {
        _container = container;
        _regionManager = regionManager;

        // Add this assembly details to a global collection
        Global.ClientAssemblies.Add(GeneralHelper.GetAssemblyInfo(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()));
    }...
```

Helper function:

```
public static string GetAssemblyInfo(Assembly assembly)
        {
            return assembly.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: I'm going to try this out. Thanks for your help. Nuno.